# Observable Subscribed, Response is returned, Can't access fields

Tags: javascript, http, angular, rxjs, observable

Here, this is my observable:

```
userLogin(formData: Object):Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(apiURL + '/api/logon', formData)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        }
    })
}
```

Then I subscribe somewhere as this:

```
this.auth.userLogin(forData)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result); // this logs the response from server object
    // console.log(result.username) doesn't work WHY?
    // Error: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Response'
  })
```

So what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Console.log outputs this:

```
Object {
    pappassword:"2f636cc3f8ffeda00dfe448fc483ce3"
    success:true
    uamip:"192.168.182.1"
    uamport:"3990"
    username:"jh"
    userurl: "http://www.gstatic.com/generate_20"
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output of console.log(result);? Everything seems alright to me. It could be just a type error as the property 'result' actually does not exist on type Response.

Comment: You are returning Observable<Response> from your service. But you should be returning Observable<Object> or better yet, create your own data model and return Observable<Identity> (I would believe a model called Identity would be suitable for your case).

Comment: @SabbirRahman updated the question with the console response.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan No, not exactly. I can't do a `result.username`. Could you hold on a sec with your closing offtopic thing?

Comment: Error: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Response' <- You are getting this error from the compiler, and for a good reason. Response object does not have property username. Change 'userLogin(formData: Object):Observable<Response>' to 'userLogin(formData: Object):Observable<any>'

Comment: @AnttiVäyrynen Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The return type userLogin method should be `Observable<T>`, here T represent your response datatype/interface. You can create an interface with your response data model and use that as your datatype.

```
interface UserInterface {
  pappassword: string
  success: boolean
  uamip: string
  uamport: string
  username: string
  userurl: string
}
```

And in your userLogin method:

```
userLogin(formData: Object):Observable<UserInterface> {
  ...
}
```

We could have just use `Observable<any>` but this is the best practice with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class UserPayload{
constructor(public pappassword: string,
            public success: boolean,
            public uamip: string,
            public uamport: string,
            public username: string,
            public userurl: string){}//using ts shorthand for properties in constructor
}

userLogin(formData: Object):Observable<UserPayload> {
return this.http.post(apiURL + '/api/logon', formData)
    .map((response: UserPayload) => {
        return response.json();
    }).catch((error:any)=> Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server Error'));
}

this.auth.userLogin(forData)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result); // this logs the response from server object
     console.log(result.username); //this should work now
 },
 e=>{console.log(e)}
 );
```